# set default value is subquery output

Tags: mysql

I would like to set the default value of a DateTime column is the output of subquery '`CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+0:00')`';

It means by the default value of the DateTime column should be DateTime in GMT timezone.

Is it possible?

Comment: There's no subquery here

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, `COALESCE` might help:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Sorry,But i think you misunderstand my question.
I would like to set default value of column is datetime in gmt timezone.Not server timezone.

Comment: Hmm... I think I see now. Have you tried to do `DEFAULT (CONVERT_TZ(...))`? I'm not sure if that's a closure, though... or whether `@@session` is available there. Anyways, what I would do is chose the column type without timezone or do the conversion on insert to do it more explicit.